# Determining the optimal suspension location for jewelry

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, geometry, 3d-printing

I'm creating jewelry with Blender and I'm wondering about finding/calculating the optimal suspension location.
Looking at the image I uploaded, you see a small eyelet.
I've used the chain simulation with rigid body physics, using higher than default iterations, etc.
However the chain keeps dangling like crazy even after a few thousand frames.

I would love a few hints to create a more quiet 'gravity simulation environment' to see what happens when I move the eyelet further to the centre or to the outside. What do you suggest?

Thanks in advance,

Wim Roskam
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the origin of your object at the center of its volume.

[image: center of volume]

- Create a passive rigibody.
- Make the jewelry an active rigidbody.

  - Increase the positional and angular damping.
- Connect both with a point constraint where the 'hook' is supposed to be.
- Simulate the rigid body simulation.

[image: rigibody setup]